# How do you make chlorophyte bars in Terraria?

Tags: terraria-console

I've recently gotten a Drax in Terraria 3DS. I discovered that I can mine the ore. I don't know what I should do with it. I have two Drax's, should I mine the ore? I haven't defeated any of the three mechanical bosses yet. Is it possible to even make the ores? I have proper anvils, and a titanium forge. Is it possible to make the bars this early ?

The only bosses that I've defeated in hardmode is the Queen Bee (an easy mode enemy), and the Eater of Souls, Brain of Cthulhu, and Eye of Cthulhu. I defeated the Wall of Flesh, but barely. I died, but a second later, the Wall of Flesh was defeated with my beenades.

Is this a good option?

Comment: i feel as though this might be considered as cheating ??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to make chlorophyte bars early on in 3DS versions of the game. As noted on the [official wiki](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Chlorophyte_Ore), all you need is an Adamantite or Titanium Forge.

The same wiki page also mentions that you can start mining chlorophyte once you have a Pickaxe Axe or Drax. There's a special note there that explains that on the 3DS version, you can find the Drax very early via shadow chests. The wiki page for the [Drax](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Drax) itself also states that it can be found during pre-hardmode, giving a huge advantage.

If you think this strategy is "cheating" or makes the game too easy, just don't use it.